# Can not connect to SQL Lite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am a beginner of Android developer. I want to develop application that connect to SQL-LITE. But I can not solve the problem. I attach my Logcat in this post too. If it is possible please post your code and the solution to solve the problem, because I am a beginner. Sorry for my ENglish. 
These are my code.

Class SimpleNoteActivity

```
import java.util.Date;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import static com.example.sudoku.Constants.*;
import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;

public class SimpleNoteActivity extends Activity{
    private NotesHelper helper;
    private static String[] COLUMNS= {_ID, TIME, CONTENT};
    //private static String[] COLUMNS= {_ID, CONTENT};
    private static String ORDER_BY = TIME+" DESC";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note); 
        helper = new NotesHelper(this);
        try{

            Cursor cursor = getAllNotes();
            showNotes(cursor);

    }
        finally{
            helper.close();
        }


        final EditText txtNewText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_text);
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                addNote(txtNewText.getText().toString());
                Cursor cursor = getAllNotes();
                showNotes(cursor);
                txtNewText.setText(null);
                }
            finally{
                helper.close();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private void addNote(String str){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(CONTENT, str);
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    }
    private Cursor getAllNotes(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, null,null,null,null,ORDER_BY);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }
    private void showNotes(Cursor cursor){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Message:\n\n");

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            long time = cursor.getLong(1);
            String content = cursor.getString(2);
            builder.append("No ").append(id).append(": ");
            String strDate = (String)DateFormat.format("yyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss",new Date(time));
            builder.append(strDate).append("\n");
            builder.append("\t").append(content).append("\n");


        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.all_text);
        tv.setText(builder);
    }


}
```

Interface Constant

```
public interface Constants extends BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
    public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String CONTENT = "content";
}
```

NoteHelper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import static com.example.sudoku.Constants.*;
import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;
public class NotesHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "simple_note.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public NotesHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+TIME+" INTEGER, "+CONTENT+" TEXT NOT NULL);");
        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CONTENT+" TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Logcat

```
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sudoku/com.example.sudoku.SimpleNoteActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: time (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, time, content FROM notes ORDER BY time DESC
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: time (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, time, content FROM notes ORDER BY time DESC
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at com.example.sudoku.SimpleNoteActivity.getAllNotes(SimpleNoteActivity.java:69)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at com.example.sudoku.SimpleNoteActivity.onCreate(SimpleNoteActivity.java:32)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
06-12 16:17:47.795: E/AndroidRuntime(17741):    ... 11 more
06-12 16:17:47.825: E/android.os.Debug(2035): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: It doesn't find the `time` column but the table creation code looks good to me. Have your tried uninstall the application and reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

You commented out code does not have the time column. More than likely the table already exists without the column. Go to app setting and Clear Data.

Also confirm that your code is actually being called when you expect it to be called by setting breakpoints... Or displaying some toast on the screen

Comment: If _time_ column was added after app installation - clearing data won't help. You have to reinstall application due to create new database or you can change database version and implement `onUpgrade` function.

Comment: oh... sorry, it's been a while since I did Android dev. I was under the impression that Clear Data also dropped the Sqlite DBs

Comment: It does, when you clear app data it clears all app data such as databases, shared preferences etc. A reinstall of the app, or changing the db version to implement onUpgrade would not be required to create the database